# Returning empty object from POST request (mithril w/ Node and Express)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, post, mithril.js

Currently having an issue where a object with null values for all content except ID is returned when trying to complete a POST request from my front end. I'm also not receiving any error messages in the console. I've tested my server using Insomnia and everything works as expected with my POST. I've also tried taking the body of newEntry out of curly brackets and including headers (even though Mithril's documentation doesn't show using them).

**FrontEnd**

```
const setData = formDOM => {

  const formData = new FormData(formDOM);
  console.log("formData", formData)
  const newEntry = {};

  Array.from(formData.entries()).map(entryValue => {
    const key = entryValue[0];
    const value = entryValue[1];

    switch (value) {
      case "false":
        newEntry[key] = false;
        break;
      case "true":
        newEntry[key] = true;
        break;
      default:
        newEntry[key] = value;
        break;
    }
  });

  console.log("new entry", newEntry)

  m.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/santaslist',
    body: {
      newEntry
    }
  }).then((person) => {
    console.log("updated entry", person)
  });
}


const EntryForm = {


  // state
  data: {
    name: "",
    street: "",
    state: "",
    city: "",
    zipcode: "",
    nice: false,
    naughty: false,
    clicked: false,
  },

  // const { name, street, state, city, zipcode, nice, naughty } = data,

  view: (vnode) => (

    <form name="entry-form" id="entry-form">

       ...

      <button
        class="ui-button"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#exampleModal"
        onclick={() =>
        { setData(vnode.dom)}
        }
      > Add </button>

     ...

    </form >
  ),
};

export default EntryForm;
```

**BackEnd**

```
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const pool = require("./db")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

// middleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())//req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }))
//ROUTES//

//create a list item (POST)
app.post("/santaslist", async(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    // console.log(req.headers)
    // console.log(res)
    try {
        const { name, street, city, state, zipcode, naughty, nice } = req.body


        const newListItem = await pool.query("INSERT INTO listitems(name, street, city, state, zipcode, naughty, nice) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING *",[name, street, city, state, zipcode, naughty, nice])

        res.json(newListItem.rows)
    } catch (err){

        console.error(err.message)
    }
})
```

["new entry" and "updated entry" console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35nmY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out, instead of body I used the data option.

```
m.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/santaslist',
    // body: newEntry,
    data: newEntry
  }).then((person) => {

    // addPersonToList(person)
    console.log("updated entry", person)

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit overcomplicated and you're using the wrong method IMO. `map` is for creating a new array with the elements of an existing array transformed. What you want is `forEach`.

Try this instead.

```js
let newEntry = {};

(formData.entries()).forEach(entry => {
  const [key, value] = entry;

  newEntry[key] = value === "true" ? true : false;
})
```

**Update**

As you specified in your response that the `formData.entries()` is an object and not an array, it should be noted that you cannot map over an object. However, you can do a `for` loop:

```js
const entries = formData.entries();
let newEntry = {};

for (const key in entries)
  newEntry[key] = entries[key] === "true" ? true : false;
})
```

Comment: I can't use a forEach because the data I'm working with is a object.

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: sorry maybe I should have clarified, even when I have hard coded the object and haven't used a map I've received an empty object from the body. My issue isn't getting the data, its the  passing of  the data where the problem occurs.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it appears the issue may be that you're using multiple body parsing middlewares. You don't need both `express.json()` and `bodyParser.json()`. In fact, if you're using the latest Express version, you don't need `bodyParser` at all. What I suspect may be happening is that it's re-parsing the already parsed object and mangling it.